# Ring isomorphism $\mathbb{Z}[x]/J \cong \mathbb{Z}_5[x]/\langle x^2-2\rangle$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Consider $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, we know that this is not a PID. Now consider the ideal $J = \langle x^2-2, 5\rangle$. I need to prove that 
$\mathbb{Z}[x]/J \cong \mathbb{Z}_5[x]/\langle x^2-2\rangle$.

Looking for a hint, will complete the proof.

Comment: Hint: there is nothing special about this case: in general, $R/(I + J) \cong (R/I)/(J/I)$.

Comment: @Magdiragdag could you specify R,I and J in the question... is R, Z or Z[x]?

Comment: In context: $R = {\mathbb Z}[x]$, $I = \langle 5\rangle$, $J = \langle x^2 - 2\rangle$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint :** Consider the composition of surjections
$$\Bbb Z[x]\to \Bbb Z_5[x]\to \dfrac{\Bbb Z_5[x]}{\langle x^2-2\rangle}$$and find its kernel. Then apply the first isomorphism theorem.

*Additional hint :* To find the kernel of a composition $f\circ g$, notice that $$x\in \ker (f\circ g) \Leftrightarrow f(g(x))=0\Leftrightarrow g(x)\in \ker f.$$
By the way this proof strategy works for the general case mentioned by Magdiragdag in the comments.

Comment: how do  you find the kernel of a composition could you pls expand on your answer